# angular subscribe return object Object not string

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, frontend, observable

I have a function like this.

```
public static getStepImage(step, connection) {
    switch (step) {
        case label.ASSIGN:
            return label.IMAGE_DIRECTORY + "Assign.svg";
        case E2wStepType.NOTIFICATION:
            return label.IMAGE_DIRECTORY + "Notification.svg";
        case E2wStepType.SERVICE:
                return connection.getConnection(step.connection);
        default:
            return label.IMAGE_DIRECTORY + "Empty.svg";
    }
}
```

The function `getStepImage` executed in `_createRectangularStep`

```
`private static _createRectangularStep(steps, connectionRepoService: E2wConnectionRepoService) {
  let rectSteps = steps.filter(
        step => editUnit.isRectangularStep(step) || editUnit.isUnknownStep(step) ? step : null);
  rectSteps.append("image")
            .attr('x', step => LabelProvider.getStepImageInset(step).x)
            .attr('y', step => LabelProvider.getStepImageInset(step).y)
            .attr("xlink:href",  step => LabelProvider.getStepImage(step, connectionRepoService).subscribe(
                    (val: any) => {
                        console.log(val.icon);
                        return val.icon;
                    }
            ))
}
```

`

The `console.log(val.icon)` show `images/logo.svg` but attr `href` get `[object Object]`

Comment: Just return `return connection.getConnection(step);` without making a subscription

Comment: Did any of the answers below solve your problem or is this still a problem for you?

Comment: I will check soon, thx

Answer (score 3):

```js
// Your code that isn't working:
/*public static getData(data, connection) {
  switch (data) {
    case 'user':
      return "this is user";
    case 'admin':
      let tmp: string;
      connection.getConnection(step).subscribe(conn => {
        tmp= conn.name;
      });
      return tmp;
    default:
      return 'empty';
  }
}*/

// How you need to rewrite your code (for RxJS v2-4):
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
// (for RxJS v5):
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

public static getData(data, connection) {
  switch (data) {
    case 'user':
      // (RxJS v2-4)
      return Observable.of({ name: "this is user" });
      // (RxJS v5)
      // return of({ name: 'this is user' });
    case 'admin':
      return connection.getConnection(step);
    default:
      // (RxJS v2-4)
      return Observable.of({ name: 'empty' });
      // (RxJS v5)
      // return of({ name: 'empty' });
  }
}

// Based on your edits, here is how I would rewrite your function. I can't guarantee that it will work perfectly because these two libraries handle data so differently:
private static _createRectangularStep(steps, connectionRepoService: E2wConnectionRepoService) {
  steps.append("image")
    .attr('x', step => LabelProvider.getStepImageInset(step).x)
    .attr('y', step => LabelProvider.getStepImageInset(step).y)
    .attr("xlink:href",  step => {
      let returnValue = '';
      LabelProvider.getStepImage(step, connectionRepoService)
        .subscribe(
          (val: any) => {
            returnValue = val;
          }
        );
      return returnValue;
    });
}
```

Comment: this is definetly the correct answer however, when using the current rxjs version it's just `of` and no longer `Observable.of`

Comment: @Nickolaus => I knew that they had updated it, but the way I wrote the code makes this compatible for Angular 2-5 (current release), since the RxJS library didn't break the backwards-compatibility. I will update my answer to include a comment of the latest change so the user can choose to use it instead.

Comment: @th3n3wguy => when I run this `MyClass.getData('user', myConnectionFunction)
  .subscribe(
    (val: { name: string; }) => val.name,
    (err) => console.error(err)
  );` I get this result `[object Object]` . But `val.name` is string

Comment: @th3n3wguy => I use this function in this and get `[object Object]`                           `.attr("xlink:href", step => LabelProvider.getStepImage(step, connectionRepoService).subscribe(
                (val: { icon: string; }) => {
                    return val.icon
                },
                (err) => console.error(err)
            )`  [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/pa78zouz/)

Comment: @ТарасМацюк => Which library are you using there? It looks like D3.js. Also, if you could edit your original post with more code samples as to where you are calling this function, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: @th3n3wguy => after your update attr `href` get empty value ` console.log(returnValue)` does not changed, it's stay ' '

Comment: @ТарасМацюк => The only other thing I can think of is for you to set all of this data in your `ngAfterViewInit()` or `ngOnInit()` function based on the data that you bind to the D3 visualization for the `steps` that is passed into this function. That's really what I would do. If you could create a JSFiddle with your full function, I could probably help you better.